redirect to api gateway service loop
I'm trying to develop a custom gateway api with ktor.
I implemented a redirect to the specific service based on the path with a factory but I think I'm using HttpClient wrong.
The problem is that when the service is down, a call loop is created that is stopped only by the rate limit.
maybe I'm architecturally wrong, Can you help me?
code:
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    val client = HttpClient() {
        expectSuccess = true
        followRedirects = false
    }
    routing {
        route("/") {
            post("{...}") {
                val reqUriPaths = call.request.uri  // <--- loop started
                serviceLog.info("request: $reqUriPaths")
                val serviceUrl: String = RoutingFactory.serviceUrlFromUri(reqUriPaths) ?: run {
                    serviceLog.error("Unable to recover path from: $reqUriPaths", Exception())
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Unable to recover path")
                    return@post
                }
                try {
                    val backendResponse: HttpResponse = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        client.request("$serviceUrl$reqUriPaths") { //<--- this is the problem
                            method = HttpMethod.Post
                            call.request.headers.forEach { header, values ->
                                headers.appendAll(header, values)
                            }
                            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
                            val body = call.receiveText()
                            setBody(body)

                            serviceLog.info("execution context: $executionContext")

                        }
                    }
                    val body = backendResponse.bodyAsText()
                    serviceLog.info("auth response service: ${backendResponse.status}")
                    call.respond(backendResponse.status, body)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    serviceLog.error("Error communicating with auth service: ${e.message}", e)
                    call.respond(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Internal server error")
                }

            }
        }
    }
}

class RoutingFactory {
    companion object {
        fun serviceUrlFromUri(uri: String): String? {
            val servicePath = uri.split("/").getOrNull(1) ?: return null
            return when (servicePath) {
                "user" -> "http://auth:8080"
                else -> null
            }
        }
    }

}

logs:

INFO  APIGateway - request: /user
INFO  APIGateway - execution context: SupervisorJobImpl{Active}@3d60ee26
INFO  APIGateway - request: /user
INFO  APIGateway - execution context: SupervisorJobImpl{Active}@6b7a58a9
INFO  APIGateway - request: /user
INFO  APIGateway - execution context: SupervisorJobImpl{Active}@452be7d9
INFO  APIGateway - request: /user
INFO  APIGateway - execution context: SupervisorJobImpl{Active}@79ceb296
INFO  APIGateway - request: /user
INFO  APIGateway - execution context: SupervisorJobImpl{Active}@7dbfead6
ERROR APIGateway - Error communicating with auth service: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 429 Too Many Requests. Text: ""
io.ktor.client.plugins.ClientRequestException: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 429 Too Many Requests. Text: ""
APIGateway - Error communicating with auth service: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""
io.ktor.client.plugins.ClientRequestException: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""
ERROR APIGateway - Error communicating with auth service: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""
io.ktor.client.plugins.ClientRequestException: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""
ERROR APIGateway - Error communicating with auth service: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""
io.ktor.client.plugins.ClientRequestException: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""
ERROR APIGateway - Error communicating with auth service: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""
io.ktor.client.plugins.ClientRequestException: Client request(POST http://auth:8080/user) invalid: 404 Not Found. Text: ""

